# Where is the official, extensive, complete documentation on web.config?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, documentation, web-config

I'm trying to find about ALL the possible options that I can set in `web.config`.
Surprisingly, I can't find this at all. I expected it to be somewhere inside [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com).

I know I can technically add "anything" to `web.config`, what I'm looking for is the things that the .NET Framework "as shipped" uses.

In particular, right now I'm interested in the `<mailsettings>` section.
For example, in many examples I've found, I noticed that they set `DeliveryMethod="Network"`. 
I'm really curious what other values this attribute can take.

Is there any document on all the attributes and all their values, and all the effects those have?

Comment: Thanks OP for this question! It's 2023 and the struggle is still real.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It all starts on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zeshe0eb(v=vs.100).aspx :

- [`<system.web>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dayb112d(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [`<system.web.extensions>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546044(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [`<appSettings>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228154(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [`<configSections>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228256(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [`<connectionStrings>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for plowing through that frustrating MSDN forest for us!

Comment: Sadly all the above documentation is "no longer supported" by Microsoft :-(

Comment: My 2 cents: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/iis/configuration/

Answer (score 3):

The links contained in the previous answers have gone bad, but this SO question is the second Google search result I got for "asp.net web.config documentation".

In the hopes of aiding the next searcher who comes through here looking for the official documentation, here is an msdn.microsoft.com link that (as of November 28th, 2012) works just fine:

[ASP.NET Configuration Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5ysx397%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: 2018 here :)  The link provided is now marked as deprecated. Any idea where to look now? :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're after (not all in one page), but the top of the schema - drill down recursively to find it all :)

[ASP.NET Configuration Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b5ysx397(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I also found this, specifically for the <mailsettings> section:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k.aspx